# EEA Family Permit Access UK or Visa4uk?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I'm applying for the EEA Family Permit to join my husband who holds a German passport and is living in the UK.

When doing the process online the gov.uk site sent us to the visa4uk website, however, after the registration a box saying that we can now use a new service appeared and we ended up filling the application through AccessUK, we even booked an appointment date through that service.

Now I'm trying to register at the application centre (VFS) but the site throws a different GWF Number that is not mine and when I try to change it through My applications a message sayin 'data not found' appears.

While doing some research online I found that some sites say that access UK is only available for certain types of visa however when we did the process through the site the EEA Family Permit was among the ones that were available.

I'm really confused and desperate now as our appointment through access UK is on the 27 but I can't register it with the visa centre.

Does anyone have know if our application through access UK is valid?

Comment: This probably belongs on [Expatriates.SE] since you seem to be seeking to establish residence in the UK.  EEA family permit questions can be ambiguous, however, since the EEA family permit can be used both for relocation and for short-term visits.